# Anyone know how to fix illegal target for anotation

Tags: python, python-3.x

was making some code and i ran into the error here is the code

```
import random
foo = ['sad', 'mad', 'happy ', 'inbetween', 'bored']
print("hello answer 1 or 2 or 3")
e = input(str)


if e == '1' : print("ok give me a sentence and ill tell you how i feel about it") ;a = input("please enter a sentence ")  ;a == ('i hate you')  :print(" i feel sad and mad that you hate me") ;a == ('I hate you') :print("i feel sad and mad that you hate me")
elif e == '2' :print("ok ill give you advice")
elif e == '3' :print("so you want to have a converstation")
else :print(" thats not an option")
```

Comment: Have the body of the `if` block indented and spanning multiple lines. What you are trying to do doesn't look like Python. The `elif` blocks should also be indented in their own lines. There is a place for a 1-line `if` statement. This isn't it.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734530 is a close enough duplicate? There are a few questions about this error message, but without a really clear canonical.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal reproducible example for this:

```
>>> if True: True: print('x')
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation
```

The problem is that the second `True` was intended to be another `if` condition, but is instead just an expression. The parser treats `: print('x')` as a [type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations) for `True`; but type annotations have to be applied to individual variable names, not expressions.

The specific error is only possible because `print('x')` is an expression, and thus a valid type annotation. If it were another kind of statement, this would cause a generic syntax error:

```
>>> if True: True: pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if True: True: pass
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Either way, there was a typo here - the second `True:` was meant to be `if True:`. However, this **does not fix the problem by itself**:

```
>>> if True: if True: pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if True: if True: pass
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It is not permitted to put multiple `if`s on the same line; nor can `elif` and `else` be paired with the matching `if` on the same line:

```
>>> if True: pass; else: pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if True: pass; else: pass
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Putting multiple statements on a line - by using semicolons, and/or by putting the "suite" of an `if` etc. statement on the same line - is strongly discouraged in Python**. It has multiple limitations, and makes the code much harder to read.

To make the example work, use indented blocks in the normal way:

```
if True:
    if True:
        pass
```

Comment: Technically, `True: print('x')` reproduces the error message, so this example is not *quite* minimal; but the point here is to highlight the issue with trying to nest `if`s.